# Can't get past Call Mediator in custom mediation flow in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator

Created custom mediation flow in WSO2 AM 1.10 in order to achieve API chaining. As a first step i created this flow, as a test, which calls a REST service in order to generate a token and returns the response to the client.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="ppayload" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
  <property name="uri.var.x" scope="default" type="STRING" value="5"/>
  <property name="uri.var.y" scope="default" type="STRING" value="5"/>
  <log level="custom" separator=",">
    <property expression="get-property('uri.var.y')" name="y"/>
    <property expression="get-property('uri.var.x')" name="x"/>
  </log>
  <call>
    <endpoint>
      <http method="get" trace="enable" uri-template="https://192.88.65.18:9443/am/sample/calculator/v1/api/add?x={uri.var.x}&amp;y={uri.var.y}"/>
    </endpoint>
  </call>
  <respond/>
</sequence>
```

However, after timeout the client receives a "no response from server". But in the logs i see the API Gateway receives the correct response it just doesn't forward it to the client.

Plus i tried adding log mediator after the call mediator to log the response but nothing that comes after the call mediator in the sequence is executed.

```
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "GET /c/1.0.0 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Authorization: Bearer c5836f1cb43350b803cb39c706c1c7ce[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Referer: https://192.88.65.18:9443/store/apis/info?name=C&version=1.0.0&provider=admin[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Language: fr-FR[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Host: 192.88.65.18:8243[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=4308DDC996DAAE6B65F183E65931DE14; requestedURI="../../carbon/mediation-tracer/index.jsp?region=region4&item=mediation_tracer_menu"; region1_configure_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; i18next=fr-FR; selectedTab=view; current-breadcrumb=monitor_menu%2Cmediation_tracer_menu%23; MSG14682483937790.7211503494363702=true; MSG14683265253540.54003207439675=true; MSG14683266178700.10747833380176508=true; MSG14688271624980.9002550537769108=true; MSG14688272096380.869345530960711=true; MSG14688276939770.25641217913473224=true; MSG14688285230820.7837411368495956=true; MSG14688303649840.057579581328428775=true; MSG14688354130800.8363238567475415=true; MSG14688444175760.4841881764888184=true; region4_monitor_menu=visible; region3_registry_menu=visible; csrftoken=rg0quh61dsudlg02rvus1qs491; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=monitor[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,195] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,200]  INFO - LogMediator y = 5,x = 5
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "GET /am/sample/calculator/v1/api/add?x=5&y=5 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "Cookie: JSESSIONID=4308DDC996DAAE6B65F183E65931DE14; requestedURI="../../carbon/mediation-tracer/index.jsp?region=region4&item=mediation_tracer_menu"; region1_configure_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; i18next=fr-FR; selectedTab=view; current-breadcrumb=monitor_menu%2Cmediation_tracer_menu%23; MSG14682483937790.7211503494363702=true; MSG14683265253540.54003207439675=true; MSG14683266178700.10747833380176508=true; MSG14688271624980.9002550537769108=true; MSG14688272096380.869345530960711=true; MSG14688276939770.25641217913473224=true; MSG14688285230820.7837411368495956=true; MSG14688303649840.057579581328428775=true; MSG14688354130800.8363238567475415=true; MSG14688444175760.4841881764888184=true; region4_monitor_menu=visible; region3_registry_menu=visible; csrftoken=rg0quh61dsudlg02rvus1qs491; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=monitor[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "Referer: https://192.88.65.18:9443/store/apis/info?name=C&version=1.0.0&provider=admin[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "Accept-Language: fr-FR[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "Host: 192.88.65.18:9443[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,204] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,205] DEBUG - wire >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,206] DEBUG - wire >> "Date: Wed, 20 Jul 2016 10:13:42 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,206] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,206] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 18[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,206] DEBUG - wire >> "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,206] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,206] DEBUG - wire >> "{"answer": "10.0"}"
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,208] ERROR - ContinuationStackManager Resource : null not found
[2016-07-20 12:13:42,214] ERROR - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse encountered an exception, No error handlers found - [Message Dropped]
Resource : null not found
[2016-07-20 12:13:54,738]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-07-20 12:13:54,738+0200]
[2016-07-20 12:14:24,850]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-43
[2016-07-20 12:14:42,259]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-44
```

Can anyone please indicate what is wrong with my configuration. Thank you.

Comment: Any Update on the below mentioned issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an already fixed bug (See [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4242)), with [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/commit/c44febfd813ff5aa8f59cdd77e492e12c7535445) commit. May be you can patch it manually since it is a small fix until you get the next release. Source for 1.10 release is [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/releases/tag/v5.0.3).

Comment: Thanks Lahiru for your answer. I installed the new release WSO2 API Manager 2.0. However it still doesn't work. I get the same error i got for the WSO2 AM 1.10.