# Bug correction in WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0

Tags: rest, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator

Does WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 still has [this](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4242) bug, which was corrected with [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/commit/c44febfd813ff5aa8f59cdd77e492e12c7535445) commit?

I'm asking because I had the bug when I used WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 and now when i started using WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 I still get the same errors. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478657/cant-get-past-call-mediator-in-custom-mediation-flow-in-wso2-api-manager) question for more details on the errors.

Edit:
The error i get after trying the `blocking=true` call

```
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,800] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "GET /call/1.0.4/mediator HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,800] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Authorization: Bearer 40bc5679-00c9-33cf-93b8-6fc5baa6f4c0[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,800] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Referer: https://192.88.68.11:9448/store/apis/info?name=Call&version=1.0.4&provider=admin[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept-Language: fr-FR[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Host: 192.88.68.11:8248[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Cookie: region3_registry_menu=visible; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; JSESSIONID=87FED1FBE54FBFBFDD8100053AA8A5F3; requestedURI="../../carbon/admin/index.jsp?loginStatus=true"; region1_configure_menu=none; region4_monitor_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; i18next=fr-FR; current-breadcrumb=registry_menu%2Cresource_browser_menu%23; csrftoken=7n1a71hhiuqbu8vk6ia6eaa9ar[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> GET /call/1.0.4/mediator HTTP/1.1
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,803] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Authorization: Bearer 40bc5679-00c9-33cf-93b8-6fc5baa6f4c0
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,803] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Accept: application/json
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,803] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Referer: https://192.88.68.11:9448/store/apis/info?name=Call&version=1.0.4&provider=admin
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,803] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Accept-Language: fr-FR
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,804] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,804] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,804] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Host: 192.88.68.11:8248
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,804] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[2016-09-08 15:08:22,804] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 >> Cookie: region3_registry_menu=visible; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; JSESSIONID=87FED1FBE54FBFBFDD8100053AA8A5F3; requestedURI="../../carbon/admin/index.jsp?loginStatus=true"; region1_configure_menu=none; region4_monitor_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; i18next=fr-FR; current-breadcrumb=registry_menu%2Cresource_browser_menu%23; csrftoken=7n1a71hhiuqbu8vk6ia6eaa9ar
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,793]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaGet to url[http://192.88.64.163:5000/v3/users/mediator]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:326)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaGet(HTTPSender.java:105)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:63)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:283)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:194)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.handleBlockingCall(CallMediator.java:125)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator.mediate(CallMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:57)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleRequest(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:300)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:319)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:152)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,796]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 401000, ERROR_MESSAGE = Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,800] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Cookie: region3_registry_menu=visible; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; JSESSIONID=87FED1FBE54FBFBFDD8100053AA8A5F3; requestedURI="../../carbon/admin/index.jsp?loginStatus=true"; region1_configure_menu=none; region4_monitor_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; i18next=fr-FR; current-breadcrumb=registry_menu%2Cresource_browser_menu%23; csrftoken=7n1a71hhiuqbu8vk6ia6eaa9ar
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Referer: https://192.88.68.11:9448/store/apis/info?name=Call&version=1.0.4&provider=admin
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Accept-Language: fr-FR
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2016 13:08:23 GMT
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,801] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-4 << Connection: Keep-Alive
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Cookie: region3_registry_menu=visible; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; JSESSIONID=87FED1FBE54FBFBFDD8100053AA8A5F3; requestedURI="../../carbon/admin/index.jsp?loginStatus=true"; region1_configure_menu=none; region4_monitor_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; i18next=fr-FR; current-breadcrumb=registry_menu%2Cresource_browser_menu%23; csrftoken=7n1a71hhiuqbu8vk6ia6eaa9ar[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Referer: https://192.88.68.11:9448/store/apis/info?name=Call&version=1.0.4&provider=admin[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Accept-Language: fr-FR[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2016 13:08:23 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "e3[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>401000</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized</am:description></am:fault>[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2016-09-08 15:08:23,802] DEBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: It should be fixed in 2.0.0. Does it behave the the same way (i.e. timeout) with 2.0.0 for you?

Comment: Yes it does. I get the exact same error and then the timeout.

Comment: Do you get the same with `blocking=true` call?

Comment: Thanks @Bhathiya for your answer, yes i tried the blocking=true call and I get this error (i updated the post with the wire logs)